# Getting the process id of a process using the process name in perl

Tags: perl

Sorry but perl\linux noob here.

I am trying to do something as simple as finding the process id of a process in perl. This seems like a fairly simple thing to do in bash itself however would appreciate some help here.

1. I first installed the Proc::Find module that i found on CPAN, this has the following syntax

   my $pids = find_proc(name => 'my-app-name');
   print "pid = $pids\n";

however the result i get here is something like

```
pid = ARRAY(0x55f5069e1c98)
```

so i tried de-referencing the array by doing the following

```
print "pid = $pids[0]\n";
```

but this did not help either since this returns nothing.

2. Next I thought, I could run some bash commands from perl and see if that works

   my $pid = `pgrep -f signalapp`
   print "pid=$pid\n";

but this just gives me a compilation error when i run this.

Comment: `$pids` is an `arrayref`. See here [Proc::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Find#find_proc(%args)-=%3E-\@pids-(or-\@procs))

Comment: Re "*so i tried de-referencing the array by doing the following*", That doesn't dereference the reference, and strict would have told you as much. ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent!

Comment: yes, thank you. am going to use strict and warnings by default from now. I added these to the perl script to see what kind of guidance i would get and it does tell me that i am missing global @pids.                       
Global symbol "@pids" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @pids"?) at ./sendsignal.pl line 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proc::Find::find_proc returns an reference to an Array, not an Array.

So the correct code would be:

```
 my $pids = find_proc(name => 'my-app-name'); 
 foreach my $pid (@$pids) {
     print "pid = $pid\n";
 }
 # or use  
 # print "pid = ". $pids->[0] . "\n"; 
 # or 
 # print "pid = $pids->[0]\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

in firs line:

```
my $pids = find_proc(name => 'my-app-name');
```

find_proc() function returns an array as an output, but not a direct array, but a reference to an array. $pid is a reference to an array

we use the following syntax to read a reference to an array

```
@$pid
```

Which shows that we are reading an array stored in a reference, so for read one item from this reference we need use one of this syntax

```perl
print "pid = $$pid[0]\n"; 
#or
print "pid = ${ $pid }[0]\n"; 

    # or

print "pid = $pid->[0]\n";
```

---

and for second line:

```
print "pid = $pids\n";
```

To display each item in a separate line, we can modify this line as follows

```perl
#one liner:
print "pid: $_\n" foreach @$pid;

#or:
foreach my $item (@$pid) {
    print "pid: $item \n";
}

#or:
foreach (@$pid) {
    print "pid: $_ \n";
}
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)[array](/questions/tagged/array)[reference](/questions/tagged/reference)